# make issue, the last argument must be 8 bit immediate

Tags: make

Please can anyone help, cant seem to find a fix or understand what I should try with this c++ program

```
 plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~/itpp-4.3.1/build$ make 
[  1%] Building CXX object itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/random.cpp.o
In file included from /home/plutes/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random_dsfmt.h:40:0,
                 from /home/plutes/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random.h:32,
                 from /home/plutes/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random.cpp:29:
/home/plutes/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random_dsfmt.h: In static member function ‘static void itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::do_recursion(typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*, typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*, typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*, typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*) [with int MEXP = 19937; int POS1 = 117; int SL1 = 19; long unsigned int MSK1 = 4498102069230399; long unsigned int MSK2 = 4501400546508797; long unsigned int FIX1_V = 10376655713290109737; long unsigned int FIX2_V = 4291106551315987578; long unsigned int PCV1_V = 4432916062321256576; long unsigned int PCV2_V = 1]’:
/home/plutes/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random_dsfmt.h:306:17: error: the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate
     __m128i y = _mm_shuffle_epi32(lung->si, SSE2_SHUFF);
                 ^
itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/build.make:422: recipe for target 'itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/random.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/random.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:87: recipe for target 'itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods here:

- compile latest Git-source
- use official Ubuntu packages from repository (**preffered** way)

## Use latest source from Git

The latest itpp-4.3.1.tar.bz2 does not compile on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as you already wrote. But it compiles normally on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with GCC 5.4.

I have just found that developers have new special [commit to fix the error](https://sourceforge.net/p/itpp/git/ci/bb5c7e95f40e8fdb5c3f3d01a84bcbaf76f3676d/). So we can install source version with:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool build-essential cmake git \
libblas-dev liblapack-dev libfftw3-dev
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/itpp/git itpp-git
cd itpp-git
./autogen.sh
./configure
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

## Use official Ubuntu packages from repository

I have never used this package, but it seems that it is packaged with version 4.3.1-8 as [`libitpp-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libitpp-dev) and [`libitpp8v5`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libitpp8v5) even on 18.04 LTS. So you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libitpp-dev libitpp8v5
```

and then link your application to IT++ as described [in the documentation](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/linking.html).

Also you can compile some [examples](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/tutorial.html) from `libitpp-doc` package.

Comment: Thank you, I needed both them lib packages just need to read that doc now.